# fatal - machine stack overflow in critical region: al agregar gema 'wicked_pdf' y 'remotipart'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, gemfile

Tengo un error con las gemas *wicked_pdf y remotipart*. Al crear un proyecto estándar:

```
$ rails new a1
```

Funciona!

Si le agrego las gemas en Gemfile

**gem 'wicked_pdf'**

**gem 'remotipart'**

y ejecuto `$ bundle install` e inicio el servidor de rails

```
$ rails s
=> Booting Puma
=> Rails 5.2.3 application starting in development 
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
Puma starting in single mode...
* Version 3.12.1 (ruby 2.5.3-p105), codename: Llamas in Pajamas
* Min threads: 5, max threads: 5
* Environment: development
* Listening on tcp://localhost:3000
Use Ctrl-C to stop
```

Todo bien hasta aquí.

si ejecuto en el navegador http://localhost:3000

me da el siguiente error en el terminal

```
Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2019-03-29 10:34:33 -0400
Processing by Rails::WelcomeController#index as HTML
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 47ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)



fatal - machine stack overflow in critical region:
```

En el navegador:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
¿alguna idea que me ayude a salir de este atolladero?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Al parecer la última versión de la gema *wicked_pdf* tiene un error que aún no ha sido solucionado (puedes ver la incidencia [aquí](https://github.com/mileszs/wicked_pdf/issues/810)); mientras se soluciona ese problema podrías utilizar la última versión que no muestra el error (i.e. 1.1.0), solo debes especificarla en tu *Gemfile*:

```
gem 'wicked_pdf', '1.1.0'
```

Comment: Si yo estoy al tanto (ya no soy tan rockie), pero al degradar a 1.1.0, no me funciona bien la gema *will_paginate*, me da una error de parámetro en la vista cuando el listado tiene mas de una página, exactamente en: `<%= will_paginate @contactos %>` y el error que arroja es: 
`ArgumentError at /contactos wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 1) ... ... ... select_for_count will_paginate (3.0.12) lib/will_paginate/active_record.rb`

OJO, esto me funcionaba hasta que generé un nuevo *Gemfile*, una versión anterior del proyecto sin actualizar con `bundle install` funciona.

Comment: alguna idea que me pueda ayudar con la versión 1.1.0?

Comment: Ya vi que tenía, era la versión de wil_paginate, la actualicé a la última versión y funciona, queda esperar por la nueva versión de wicked_pdf

Answer (score 0):

Siguiendo de la respuesta entregada por Gerry, podrías intentar a usar los últimos cambios de master:

```
gem 'wicked_pdf', git: 'https://github.com/mileszs/wicked_pdf', branch: 'master'
```

O, como sugieren en [este comentario](https://github.com/mileszs/wicked_pdf/issues/650#issuecomment-339997704), podrías probar a hacer un monkey-patch  en `config/initializers/wicked_pdf.rb` para borrar la definición del método `render`:

```
if Gem.win_platform?
  WickedPdf.config = {
    exe_path: 'C:\wkhtmltopdf\bin\wkhtmltopdf.exes'
  }
end
class WickedPdf
  module PdfHelper
    remove_method(:render)
  end
end
```

y en su reemplazo usar `render_with_wicked_pdf`, claramente todo esto mientras aún no salga un parche oficial que al parecer [aún están trabajando en él](https://github.com/mileszs/wicked_pdf/issues/650#issuecomment-476865744).